# How do you add a page to a WinUI 3 project created with template studio?

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

I know this is a simple question but I just can't figure out how to add a new page after creating a WinUI 3 with template studio (and I don't want to make another project just to add another page). I can see that template studio auto creates a navigation helper which navigates to the pages but when i use the helpers it just throws an exception. (ShellPage.xaml)

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI_App.Views.ShellPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:helpers="using:WinUI_App.Helpers"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:WinUI_App.Behaviors"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    Loaded="OnLoaded"
    Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}">

    <NavigationView
        x:Name="navigationView"
        IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"
        IsBackEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsBackEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
        IsSettingsVisible="True"
        ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="1280"
        Header="{x:Bind ((ContentControl)ViewModel.Selected).Content, Mode=OneWay}"
        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <!--
            TODO: Change the symbols for each item as appropriate for your app
            More on Segoe UI Symbol icons: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font
            Or to use an IconElement instead of a Symbol see https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/blob/main/docs/UWP/projectTypes/navigationpane.md
            Edit String/en-US/Resources.resw: Add a menu item title for each page
            -->
            
            <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Icon="ThreeBars" helpers:NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="WinUI_App.ViewModels.MainViewModel" />
            <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_ListDetails" Icon="list" helpers:NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="WinUI_App.ViewModels.ListDetailsViewModel" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding}"
                        Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                        Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior
                DefaultHeader="{x:Bind ((ContentControl)ViewModel.Selected).Content, Mode=OneWay}">
                <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding}"
                                Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                                Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
            </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Grid>
            <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
        </Grid>
        <NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Account" Tag="SamplePage4" Icon="Contact"/>
        </NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
</Page>
```

Can anyone help me please I can share more code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you want to add a "TestPage":

1. Add a new page named **TestPage.xaml** in the **Views** folder
2. Create a **TestViewModel.cs** a `TestViewModel` class in the **ViewModels** folder and implement it. (Use other pages as a reference for how to implement it.)
3. Register `TestViewModel` class as a service in **App.xaml.cs**
4. Register `TestViewModel` and `TestPage` in **PageService.cs**
5. Add a `NavigationViewItem` for `TestPage` in **ShellPage.xaml**
6. Add a string resource in **Resources.resw** for `Shell_TestPage.Content`

Comment: I get an error trying to register TestViewModel and TestPage in PageService.cs

Error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0311 The type 'WinUI_App.Services.TestPage' cannot be used as type parameter 'V' in the generic type or method 'PageService.Configure<VM, V>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WinUI_App.Services.TestPage' to 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page'. WinUI App C:\Users\tomas\source\repos\WinUI App\Services\PageService.cs 24 Active

Comment: I redid it and found out that I messed up a part but after fixing it I now get this error:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'TestPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WinUI App C:\Users\tomas\source\repos\WinUI App\Services\PageService.cs 24 Active

Comment: The only way I could reproduce your error (CS0246) on **TestPage** is by not declaring the **TestPage**'s namespace in **PageService.cs**. Can you confirm that **TestPage** is in the same namespace with the other pages?

Comment: I forgot to change the namespace because I just copied the code from another page and forgot to change the namespace. It now works fine, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To add more pages to your project using Template Studio you could try this:

- Right-click the project in Solution Explorer
- Select Add
- Select New Item (Template Studio)
- Select New Page...
- Choose the page type, then click next etc..